# Generic vector class, make 0 size reference to generic array members;

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, generics, vector

I have a simple template vector class like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Vec {
public:

    T v[N];
    //T const& x = v[0];
    ...
}
```

Can I make references to the array members without size cost? Becuse if I write the commented out code, it will allocate the size for the pointer, is there a workaround or a #define or some kind of magic?

Comment: How about `T const& x() const { return v[0]; }`? That has no cost.

Comment: do you actually need to hold a reference, or would a function that returns the reference be what you're after

Comment: @KerrekSB beat me to it :)

Comment: @Muscampester Program size does not matter, but thank you :)

Comment: @Kerrek SB Yeah I thought about it ,but writing () everytime is not convinient.

Comment: You could use a macro, but then you won't get type safety.

Comment: @Barmar Could you write me an example macro?

Comment: But you should use a more distinctive name, otherwise you'll have problems if you try to use `x` as an ordinary variable. e.g. `#define Vec_x v[0]`. Then you can do `myvec.Vec_x = 100;`

Comment: @Ryper: Writing is not a significant part of programming. Reading and thinking are by far the most important ones; optimizing for writing is usually not a priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to add a reference-type member to a class for 0 size cost. A reference is just a fancier, safer, and more convenient pointer. It still points to some specific memory location and needs to store the address of that location.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make references to the array members without size cost?

Yes. References with automatic storage duration do not (always) need to require storage. Depending on the case, they may need to be stored on the stack, but will not grow the size of `Vec`. So, you can use a function that returns the reference:

```
T const& Vec::first() const { return v[0]; }
```

Incidentally, `std::vector` and other containers also provide similar functionality.